# Как передать массив short через send (winsock)?

Tags: c++, сокет, visual-studio-2015, клиент-сервер, winsock

Есть клиент и сервер через *TCP*. Клиент записывает звук в массив и отправляет серверу:

`short foo[512];`

Сервер должен принять и преобразовать это в тот же массив (для проигрывания звука).

Вопрос лишь в том как **преобразовать** `short foo[512];` **в** `const char *bar` для send()

И так же как его **преобразовать** уже на сервере **обратно из** `const char *bar` **в** `short foo[512];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да просто передавайте как

```
send((const char*)foo, sizeof(foo));
```

Словом, просто укажите, сколько байт передавать. Передача идет побайтово, тут тип не имеет значения. Выбран тип указателя `const char*`, к которому и приводите свой буфер.

Принимаете аналогично.

Comment: Я извиняюсь за мою тупость, но принимать аналогично это как?)

Comment: `short foo[512]; recv((char*)foo, sizeof(foo));`